How to disable image/video download and How to make CSS disabled in selenium WebDriver of JAVA
I am using Chrome WebDriver latest version of now (Version 129.0.6668.59 (Official Build) (64-bit)).
Chrome Driver version 129.0.6668.58
I want to get a title or head of any URL (Youtube, Instagram, TikTok, Blogs, News, and so on.) with minimum hardware resources. Some pages, for example, Youtube, Instagram, TikTok, are loading their title or head dynamically through javascript. So I need to run javascript files if it is related to the title or head. Since what js files are related to the title is hard to find out, I might need to run all js files available.
Anyway, I just want to get a title or head (usually h1 or h2 tag) with minimum hardware resources. How should I set the selenium ChromeOptions to get the right result?
For now, I am using the below options.
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments(/*"--headless=new", */
    "--disable-web-security",
    "--allow-running-insecure-content",
    "--disable-site-isolation-trials",
    "--disable-popup-blocking",
    "--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process",
    "--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false",
    "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/128.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "--disable-software-rasterizer",
    "--disable-blink-features",
    "--disable-browser-side-navigation",
    "--window-size=1200,640",
    "--disable-gpu",
    "--disable-notifications",
    "--disable-extensions",
    "--ignore-certificate-errors",
    "--remote-allow-origins=*",
    "--no-sandbox",
    "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
    "--port=" + curPort);
// chromeOptions.setBrowserVersion("latest");
chromeOptions.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.EAGER);
chromeOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
Duration duration = Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
chromeOptions.setScriptTimeout(duration);
chromeOptions.setPageLoadTimeout(duration);
chromeOptions.setImplicitWaitTimeout(duration);
chromeOptions.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.DISMISS_AND_NOTIFY);
curPort++;
if (curPort > MAX_PORT) { curPort = MIN_PORT; }

